# "Transfer to Phone Number" fails in Queue Flow

Tags: amazon-connect

When I use a "Transfer to Phone Number" block in a queue flow, the transfer sometimes fails and the "Error" path is used.  The same flow succeeds in other calls.  The phone number the transfer is made to is never receiving a call, and no failures are observable on the provider CDR owning the phone number.

How can I transfer without an error?

Answer (score 0):

Transfers fail if the contact is ringing on an agent's CCP, regardless of whether they pick up.  I'm not aware of any means to transfer once the call after an agent starts ringing.